# Mac: How to restore a failed external hard drive from Time Machine? [2024]

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I have an external drive which still works but I want to test the backup, which contains all my photos.
I have a second larger external drive, which i use for back up via Time Machine.

When the external drive is plugged in, i can see that my backup is there, but as soon as it is unplugged, there is no external drive in Time Machine.

I found this solution from 2012 It is basically the same problem as [Restoring external drive from time machine backup](https://superuser.com/questions/383384/restoring-external-drive-from-time-machine-backup) and in [How to restore a failed external HDD from Time Machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/1467977/how-to-restore-a-failed-external-hdd-from-time-machine) [2019]. Where the solution is to access the files manually. However on my external drive there is a ".sparsebundle"[image] which looks like this, and i can't find any user data to manually copy.

I also found this solution, which also seems more or less not working and more hassle then anything else [How to restore a failed external hard drive from Time Machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/65146/how-to-restore-a-failed-external-hard-drive-from-time-machine).

So my question, is there a way in 2024 to access the data of a lost external drive, which was backup-ed in Time Machine, without knowing the name of the old drive or using command line?

Answer (score 0):

Alright just found the answer shortly after.

I tried to access the .sparsebundle first with double-click, which ended up in an error. However it seems that Time Machine was still using the bundle, which was the cause of the error.

You need to stop Time Machine and then you can access the bundle, there you can find all files as described in the mentioned question.